# Opening UI5 Quickview by non-SAPUI5 control

Tags: d3.js, sapui5

I'm trying to integrate UI5 with other libraries(namely D3) and am unable to open a UI5 Popover(or QuickView) by my controls.

The only method I can call to open the popover is `.openBy(control)`.

According to the UI5 documentation: The Control = This is the control to which the popover will be placed. It can be not only a UI5 control, but also an existing DOM reference.

I've tried multiple things, but am unable to get the popover to open successfully. I continue to get errors in sap-ui-core.js.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to properly pass the DOM reference of my non-UI5 control?

Here is a code snippet showing what I'm trying to accomplish:

```js
// circleClicked is the SVG element clicked on the map
function openQuickView(circleClicked) {

    // quickView controls are UI5 and were created before this function
    quickViewPage.setHeader(circleClicked.created_by);

    // error
    quickView.openBy(d3.select(circleClicked));
};
```

Comment: I had a similar situation in one of my applications. I spent a long time to get it work with the Popover but faced more and more problems. What I did was to control a div container (with an unique Id) with D3 and once I want to open the popover (a tooltip in my case) I simply call `.placeAt` of my UI5 Control to inject it to the div container. The coordinates of the div container are controlled with D3´s event coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you describe seems to be correct.
According to the [documentation of sap.m.Popover](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Popover.html#openBy) you can also call `openBy` with a DOM reference as parameter.

What you are passing in your code snippet is not a DOM reference however, it is a d3 selection. To get the required DOM reference from the selection you have to add `[0][0]`([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10341307/1469028)).

```
function openQuickView(circleClicked) {
  quickViewPage.setHeader(circleClicked.created_by);
  quickView.openBy(d3.select(circleClicked)[0][0]); 
};
```

---

EDIT: After playing around with the provided fiddle I found the problem.
The parameter to the function is the datum of the clicked object, not the DOM.
You should change your click handler and the function like this:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
// ...
.on("click", function(d) {
  openQuickView(this, d);
});
function openQuickView(circleClicked, circleData) {
  quickViewPage.setHeader(circleData.created_by);
  quickView.openBy(circleClicked);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately the code above still results in errors in the SAPUI5 core: Uncaught TypeError: i.replace is not a function

Comment: Well, I only tested it with `oPopover.openBy(document.getElementById("target"))`.
Are you sure your selection is not empty?
Can you add a link to a working example of your code?

Comment: It took me awhile to get the fiddle uploaded.  Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/okhuskerfan/m05p4vef/  Hopefully my SVG and JSON files loaded correctly - should be under external resources.

Comment: Thank you hirse!!!! It is working now, I greatly appreciate your help - nice work.