# Selecting multiple dom elements by index with d3.selectAll()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm stuck on a problem where I try to select specific DOM elements with d3.selectAll(). For example let's say I have the following dataset.

```
const dataset = [3, 7, 9, 5, 4]
```

Now, I want to create SVG circles from this dataset

```
d3.selectAll("circle").data(dataset).join("circle").attr("r", 2).attr("cx", (d,i) => i * 10).attr("cy", 100)
```

Let`s say I have a button with an eventlistener that should select a random number of these circles and change their fill values. How can I implement this?

```
const button = document.querySelector("button")
button.addEventListener("click", () => { 

// what should the code be here?

}
```

I have tried some of the suggestions from [How to access the DOM element that correlates to a D3 SVG object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337640/how-to-access-the-dom-element-that-correlates-to-a-d3-svg-object) but these works only for a single dom element. Is there a way to select more than one DOM element by index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's an incongruence between your question title and your example: in the title and in the last paragraph you're asking *how to select elements by their indices*, while in the example you're asking *how to select a random number of elements*. Thus, I'll answer the title question only.

In D3 selections, the second argument passed to most selections' methods is the index. Thus, supposing you have the desired indices, e.g...

```
[1, 4, 5, 7]
```

... all you need is to use `filter`, `each` or any other direct method to change your elements. Here's a quick example, `circles` is my circle selection, and I change their fills according to the indices array:

```js
const circles = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(10))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("cx", (_, i) => i * 25 + 10)
  .attr("cy", 40);

const indicesArray = [1, 4, 5, 7];

circles.filter((_, i) => indicesArray.includes(i))
  .style("fill", "tan");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```